# Php Regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression that accept numbers, spaces and hyphen with a maximum of 8 caracters. Example 2632-632, 3636 252

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  What are you trying to do?  Is this a homework problem?

Comment: And what have you come up with by yourself?

Comment: SO is often closely followed by "DIY".

Comment: So, a string of 8 spaces is also acceptable?

Comment: I don't really understand the down-votes. Though not exactly polite, it's still a valid question from someone with no regex experience.

Comment: @Mikulas, I didn't downvote, but best guess is the tone of the question with no work/effort shown.

Comment: The tone of the question ?! I never work with regular expressions, I'm trying to understand then to validate some inputs in a form using php FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, i don't understand the discussion, stackoverflow exists for this no ?

Comment: @Sbml: Don't sweat it, man. I don't know for sure why they downvoted the question. But, hey, you got a good answer, so it's all good. Just so you know, stackoverflow folks like to see that you've put some work into trying to answer your own questions. Go figure. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
~^[\d\s-]{0,8}$~
```

Comment: This is wrong. It will accept `1234`.

Comment: @Jonathan M, besides the fact that the OP accepted this answer, why do you think it's wrong? The OP states: _"accept numbers, spaces and hyphen with a maximum of 8 caracters"_, which this pattern clearly matches (and your example `"1234"`).

Comment: Yep. Had my eyes crossed. See other spoutings on the page. Off-day. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a *regular expression that accept numbers, spaces and hyphen with a maximum of 8 caracters.*

```
/^[\d -]{1,8}$/D
```

The question is, perhaps unknowingly, ambiguous so some liberties have been taken with the details.

"*Spaces*" is taken to mean the horizontal space character ([ASCII 32](http://asciitable.com)); a minimum of 1 character is required (empty strings don't match); and contrary to the other answers a trailing newline character will not be accepted (thanks to the `D` [pattern modifier](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers)).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: `/^[\d -]{0,8}$/`

*Edit:* Since I was so flippant before, this regex now does exactly what you want: A string with digits (`\d`), spaces (), and hyphens (`-`) between 0 and 8 characters long. `\s` is for "whitespace character", which you didn't specify in the question, thus the change to .

Comment: +1 for `\s`, I'd forgotten that existed even.

Comment: -0 for `\s`, -1 for being an entirely broken regex — `{,8}` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: This will match 123 due to the comma, won't it?

Comment: Most regex implementations I know of (including PHP's `preg_` functions), do not accept `{,8}` as: "match between 0 and 8 times".

Comment: @CanSpice it will only match a single digit, whitespace or dash followed by literal characters `{,8}`... e.g. `9{,8}`

Comment: Fixed. Forgot about that. :-)

Comment: `echo preg_match('/^[\d\s-]{,8}$/', '1234') ? 'Match!' : 'Nope...';` will print `Nope...`

Comment: @CanSpice so much for "*Honestly, this is really easy:*" ;)

Comment: @Bart Kiers: See salathe's comment. That's why it didn't match.

Comment: One final word of caution (more towatds the OP): `\s` will not just match a space (or tab), but line break chars as well.

Comment: This is still wrong. It now accepts 0 to 8 characters of specified format.

Comment: @Jonathan: And what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Jonathan M, yes I knew why. But since CanSpice made a remark that this was really easy, I wanted himself to fix it. :)

Comment: @CanSpice: Duhhh! I'm having reading problems today. Sorry, man. :)

Answer (score 0):

`/^([0-9 \-]){0,8}$/` ought to work, though I haven't tested so forgive me if I have made a silly error.

Comment: @CanSpice: How so? It limits the repetition to between 0 and 8 characters

Comment: @CanSpice: Ooh didn't see that, good catch

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^(\d|\s|-){0,8}$/
```

Comment: That will match the string `012345678901234567890`, which is longer than 8 characters.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it won't. I just tested it after you posted that comment. It's really a very simple regex pattern. The "{0,8}" at the end makes sure it won't be longer than 8 characters.

EDIT: I see what you mean. If the string is what you suggested, it will only match the first part.

Comment: @BenjaminHarris, yes, I'm pretty sure it will. Try it. (hint: anchor your pattern with `^` and `$`)

Comment: actually it will match longer strings, because you don't limit it with word boundaries (\b) nor line starts/ends.

Answer (score -2):

If it must be exactly 8 chars:

```
/^[\d\s-]{8}$/
```

Comment: This is wrong, doesn't accept `1234`.

Comment: ***"with a maximum of 8 characters"*** is _not_ the same as ***"of exactly 8 characters"***

Comment: Yeah, I had my eyes crossed. I thought the OP was *exactly* 8, not maximum 8. My bad. Pile on, boys. :)

Comment: Jonathan, note that if you delete this answer, you'll get the rep-points back you just lost by the down-votes (if you're into that...) after the next rep-recalc.

Comment: @Bart Kiers, thanks, man, but that would require me moving the mouse all the way up to the top of my answer, and after it got there I'd *still* have to click. I just don't have that much energy. :)